# What is the difference between psk_ke and psk_dhe_ke as defined in RFC8446 4.2.9

Tags: tls

I assume one uses one uses dhe on top? / instead of? some other key derivation function. But I am confused as to what that actually means in practice and what the considerations are.

If we look at [RFC8446 7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-7.1), is `psk_ke` using the same key schedule as `psk_dhe_ke` but without the middle part in the diagram?

Comment: Did you read the [4.2.9](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446#section-4.2.9)? The answer to your question is there: "psk_ke:  PSK-only key establishment. / psk_dhe_ke:  PSK with (EC)DHE key establishment."

Comment: Yes, what is PSK key establishment exactly? I don't assume you just take the PSK and throw it into AES?

Comment: Look at https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446#section-7.1 and see that PSK and resumption use the same mechanism. PSK is like a resumption that was communicated to the client out-pf-band.

Comment: @Z.T. I wasn't asking about the difference between PSK and session resumption, but about the difference between PSK with and without diffie hellman.